# Drag and Drop profile avatar in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

I am beginner in web development
i want help in how to update profile image by drag and drop and then update the picture 
i search in google but all not for beginners 
i hope someone help me with any links or videos for that 
thank you

Comment: did my solution help you?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided any code or what specifically you want to do, I will be sharing the vanilla implementation of drag and drop.

To make an element draggable, you must add the`draggable=true` attribute to it.

Then, you must declare what happens when a drag event occurs using the attribute `ondragstart="drag(event)"`.

For the place (element), where the draggable element will be dragged to, you need to add the following attributes:

- `ondrop="drop(event)"`
- `ondragover="allowDrop(event)"`

You will also need to write Javascript code to handle the drag events.

You can view a complete example in the following [CodePen](https://codepen.io/TomerBenRachel/pen/zMGqwr).

```js
let otherParagraph = document.querySelector("#leftDiv")

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
 
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

    console.log(ev.target);

    let paragraph = event.target.querySelector("p");
    var temp = otherParagraph.innerHTML
    otherParagraph.innerHTML = paragraph.innerHTML;
    paragraph.innerHTML = temp;

    otherParagraph = paragraph;
  
}

function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Spicy Rice', cursive;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align:center;
}

#dragFrom {
  width: 49%;
  height: 154px;
  background: blue;
  float:left;
  color:white;
  border: 2px solid black;

}

#dragTo {
  width: 50%;
  height: 154px;
  background: green;
  float:right;
  color:white;
  border: 2px dashed black;
}

#draggableImage {
  width: 30%;
  height: 60%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  
  <head>
    <title>Drag & Drop</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Spicy+Rice" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  
  <h1>Drag & Drop</h1>
  
  <body>
    
    <div id="dragFrom"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <p id="leftDiv">Drag Me!</p>
      <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/5171QTJpI4L.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="draggableImage" alt="box">
    </div>
    
    <div id="dragTo" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <p id="rightDiv">Over Here!</p>
    </div>
  
  </body>
  
  
</html>
```